# Finding a minimum weight spanning tree?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, computer-science, trees

Letting W be the weighted graph created by taking a complete graph K5 on five vertices 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with the weight of each edge **{x,y}** given by **({x,y})=x+y**,

How would I find a minimum weight spanning tree for W?

Comment: Hi Amanda. Welcome to MSE. I noticed you asked the same question yesterday already. Please refrain from doing this in the future. If you weren't happy with the answer you received on the other question, it's ok to ask the answerer for clarification. More generally, you should always include your thoughts about a problem you are working on and describe where you're stuck. Then people can address the specific issues you might be having.

Answer (score 0):

The greedy algorithm can be used to find arbitrary minimum weight spanning trees, you just have to add the lightest edge that doesn't create a cycle at each turn.

In this case the graph will have vertices $\{1,2\},\{1,3\} ,\{1,4\},\{1,5\}$